# Does spatial depth identifies probability distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

For a probability distribution, $P$ defined on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$, we define spatial depth function $D_P:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $D_P(x)=1-\left\|E\left[\frac{X-x}{\|X-x\|_2}\right]\right\|_2$. If we have two probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and if we know $D_P(x)=D_Q(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then does that imply $P=Q$? It is true if $P$ and $Q$ are spherically symmetric about $0$. But I have no idea for general case. (Spherically symmeric distribution : If $X\sim P$ then $X$ is spherically symmitrically distributed about $0$ if $X\stackrel{d}{=}EX$ for any $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix $E$.)